# State space model with a constant disturbance term

Tags: control-theory

I have a question related with the problem shown in the title.

I got a state space model of my system through calculations and it turns out to have a form as

follows

$\dot x(t)=Ax(t)+Br(t)+c$ where A and B are constant matrixes and x and r are state variable

and input, respectivley. The final term is a constant vector with same size as $x$ and I believe it is a

disturbance term. As you can see, it strictly is not linear but I want to make it a linear

form. As I think, since $c$ can be regarded as an input(or disturbance) given to the system right at the

time reference denoted as $t = 0$, It may be represented as $w(t)=c*u(t)$ where

u(t) is a unit step function. In this way, it seems that I could get a state

space representation with multi-inputs

$\dot x(t)=Ax(t)+Br(t)+w(t)$

but I added a unit step function which was absent actually.

I want to know whether doing like this is theoretically correct (not practical view). And if it's

correct, can I get some reliable reference (sth like a paper) on this?

Thank you.

Best,

Comment: Your question is similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2559130) and my answer there can also be applied to your answer. However I do not have a reference, like a paper, for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [State space model with constant offset for harmonic balance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559130/state-space-model-with-constant-offset-for-harmonic-balance)

Answer (score 1):

This term could be considered as a shift in the input:
$$r(t)=r'(t)+a$$

$$
\dot x(t)=A x(t)+B(r'(t)+a)+c
$$

then

$$\dot x(t)=A x(t)+B r'(t)+ \underbrace{B a+c}_{=0}$$

Set $a$ in the way that
$$Ba=-c$$

In cases where B does not have enough degrees of freedom to do that then it will be questionable whether the input can compensate the effect to $c$ at all.