# What is the difference between $\dot{x} = Ax + b +Bu$ and $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$, where b is a constant vector?

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, polytopes

As an engineer, when studying control theory, a linear system is often described as $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$.

However, when reading about geometry of control spaces or on system abstraction on full-dimensional polytopes, the linear system is defined as $\dot{x} = Ax + b +Bu$, where b is a constant vector.

In the work I have read so far, the b does not play a significant role. So, I was wondering, why this b is introduced in the system definition? What is this representation motivated by?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559130) is related (mostly my answer to it I think). What do you mean by significance, the physical significance such as that the constant vector could represent a constant force/acceleration such as gravity?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen, I see your answer and that co-ordinate transformation gives Ax+Bu system from a Ax+b+Bu system. No, I do not mean physical significance, I am curious as to the mathematical significance of b? If we are doing to coord transform to go back to Ax+Bu representation, why introduce b in the first place. I was asked to read on affine systems over Banach spaces to get my answer. When I find an explanation, I shall update the post, unless someone posts an answer :)

Comment: I don't see a particular relevance of Banach spaces here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the equation as

$$\dot x-Ax=b+Bu,$$

$b$ is nothing but a constant excitation, i.e. a translation of the equilibrium point.

---

As you probably know, we can get rid of it with $y:=x+A^{-1}b$, giving

$$\dot y-Ay=Bu.$$

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it is to create a more general system. By this I mean it is a system model that is explicitly taking into account a reference input or a fixed point the system naturally operators around. I believe this is what the comment above is alluding to, as it is technically equivalent to a shift of coordinates.

If a system, $Ax+Bu$, has a control law, $u$, designed such that $x\rightarrow 0$. Then by definition the closed loop system is stable i.e. $eig(A-BK)<0$. The similar system defined by $Ax+Bu +b$ will have $x\rightarrow b$ for a $K$ such that $eig(A-BK)<0$. Therefore, any analysis done on one system also holds for the other.