# Linear Quadratic Regulator with "offset"

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

I am familiar with the LQR formulation:

$$\dot{x} = A x + B u$$

My question is: why use this formulation, and never the one with an offset:

$$\dot{x} = A x + B u + C$$

where $C$ is a constant "offset" matrix?

---

While the question is purely the "why" above, here are a few of the hypothesis of answers I could think about:

- *why does it make sense to ask for LQR with a $C$ offset?*

I suppose being able to have an "offset" would be useful, for example if there is a non-linear system with no obvious stationary points that has to be linearized around the current state to perform a "local" LQR, for example in a MPC context? In this case, I guess we should expect to have an offset $C$ matrix to appear in general?

- *if it does is interesting to look at formulations with a $C$ offset, why is this never used in LQR formulation?*

My "speculation" is that the offset is considered to be "factored in" the $Bu$ term (or the $Ax$ term), by decomposing $u = u_{stationary} + u_{control}$, where $B u_{stationary} + C = 0$ (or similarly by change of coordinates of $x = x_{stationary} + \tilde{x}$ so that $A x_{stationary} + C = 0$), and that, if such a decomposition / "projection" of $C$ onto a control (state) offset does not exist, the system is not fully controllable anyways. Is that idea correct \ wrong? How is linearizing around a local state that is not a stationary point usually handled in control theory? Is there some other explanation why we do not see an offset matrix in the fomulation of the LQR problem?

Comment: This post is quite unclear. There are many questions in there but they are not well formulated, which makes the post confusing. Please reformulate your post to make things clearer. Also, is $C$ known here?

Comment: If you have an offset you can define the augmented state variable $z=(x, c)$ where $\dot{c} = 0$ and $\dot{z} = \begin{bmatrix}A &  I\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}z + \begin{bmatrix}B\\0\end{bmatrix}u$. This way, if you have a way to solve the LQR problem for linear systems, you can do this trick and apply it to affine systems too.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis but with that adaptation the system becomes uncontrollable. A better approach would first probably be to do a coordinate transformation, as first described in [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2559245/76466).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen why would you want it to be controllable? The second part of $z$ starts at $c$ and remains there forever. It only makes sense to control $x$. You can use something like $Q=\mathrm{diag}(I, 0)$ in your LQR formulation.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis for most solvers of LQR it is either a requirement that the considered system is controllable or at least stabilizable; both of which are not the case for the augmented system.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen The objective is not to steer the system to the origin, but to some other equilibrium point. That said, the cost function should be of the form \|z-z^{\rm ref}\|_Q^2. I have a detailed formulation somewhere in my notes. I'll try to dig it up.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis the R in LQR stands for regulator, meaning to drive the state to zero. And it is easier to reformulate the state space model to match the standard model, for example using the transformation I mentioned earlier, than to try to modify the LQR itself. Though, sometimes this does require perfect knowledge of the model, which isn't always realistic and LQI (linear quadratic integrator) could be used instead of LQR.