# Simulating Derived State Space Matlab

Tags: dynamical-systems, matlab, control-theory

I've derived a state space system, where each equation had a constant term at the end. As far as I'm aware in order to perform state space analysis I should combine them into Bu like this (sorry not sure how to put them side by side):
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
a & b & 1 & 0\\
e & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2\\ 
-d\\
-g\\
\end{bmatrix}
I'm confused as to how this plays out in matlab simulation. How do you input reference values for each output in a MIMO system? If you can, how do the constants come into play? Kind of 2 questions in one.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2559245/76466).