# How to solve discrete-time algebraic ricatti equation for affine dynamical system using scipy.linalg.solve_discrete_are

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control

I am trying to solve a discrete algebraic ricatti equation for an affine dynamical system (ADS) of the form:

$$x_{t+1} = A x_t + B u_t + b$$

where $x_t, u_t$ and $b$ are vectors and $A$ and $b$ are matrices.

As described [here](https://www.khoury.northeastern.edu/home/rplatt/cs5335_2015/slides/alqr_overview.pdf), I convert the ADS to a linear dynamical system (LDS) as follows:

$$x_{t+1}^{new} = A^{new} x_t^{new} + B^{new} u_t,$$

where

$$x_t^{new} = \begin{bmatrix} x_t\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, A^{new} = \begin{bmatrix} A & b\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, B^{new} = \begin{bmatrix} B\\ 0 \end{bmatrix},$$

However, when I try to solve the discrete-time algebraic ricatti equation for this LDS by calling scipy.linalg.solve_discrete_are in python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import solve_discrete_are, solve

x_dim = 2
u_dim = 1
A = np.ones((x_dim, x_dim))
B = np.ones((x_dim, u_dim))
b = np.ones((x_dim,))

A_new = np.zeros((x_dim + 1, x_dim + 1))
A_new[:x_dim, :x_dim] = A
A_new[:x_dim, -1] = b
A_new[-1, -1] = 1

B_new = np.zeros((x_dim + 1, u_dim))
B_new[:x_dim, :] = B
B_new[-1, :] = 0

Q = np.eye(x_dim + 1)
R = np.eye(u_dim)

S = np.zeros((x_dim + 1, u_dim))
X = solve_discrete_are(A_new, B_new, Q, R, e=None, s=S)
K = solve(B_new.T @ X @ B_new + R, B_new.T @ X @ A_new + S.T)
```

I get the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../LQR.py", line 23, in <module>
    X = solve_discrete_are(A_new, B_new, Q, R, e=None, s=S)
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_solvers.py", line 716, in solve_discrete_are
    raise LinAlgError('Failed to find a finite solution.')
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Failed to find a finite solution.
```

Can you someone tell me why this isn't working and how I can make it work?

Comment: The error is saying that it didn't find a solution. Are you sure that the system you picked is solvable?

Comment: The extended system is not stabilizable. So, there is no solution to the ARE in this case.

Comment: but I get the same error even if I set b to 0 (thus changing A_new and making the system linear), even though the problem can be solved if I pass A and B (instead of A_new and B_new) to solve_discrete_are...

Comment: @Jabby The added state from A_new is uncontrollable and has an associated eigenvalue of one (which is marginally stable but not asymptotically stable).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen thank you. I thought it may be something to do with that. Can I get around this numerically? I am ultimately trying to compute the optimal feedback gain matrix K, as you can see in my last line of code.

Comment: Instead of extending the state one could also attempt to do a [coordinate transformation as mentioned here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2559245/76466). That answer is in regards to a continuous differential equation instead of discrete difference equation, but the coordinate transformation does not change between the two.

Comment: On second thought, there is a difference between discrete vs continuous time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of extending the state space model with a marginally stable state (eigenvalue of one) which is uncontrollable, one can try and see if a coordinate transformation is possible, similar to the [continuous time variant discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2559245/76466).

If your system is of the form

$$
x_{k+1} = A\,x_k + B\,u_k + f \\
y_k = C\,x_k + D\,u_k + g \tag{1}
$$

with $x_k$, $u_k$ and $y_k$ the state, input and output of the system respectfully at time step $k$, $f$ and $g$ constant vectors. The following coordinate transformation could be used to make the affine system linear $z_k=x_k+\alpha$ and $v_k=u_k+\beta$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ constant vectors which satisfy

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A-I & B \\ C & D
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha \\ \beta
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
f \\ g
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{2}
$$

This can always be solved if the $(A-I,B,C,D)$ matrix is full rank and if this is not the case when the vector of $(f,g)$ lies in the span of the $(A-I,B,C,D)$ matrix. After this transformation the dynamics will simply be

$$
z_{k+1} = A\,z_k + B\,v_k \\
y_k = C\,z_k + D\,v_k. \tag{3}
$$

It can be noted that when applying a control technique to $(3)$, which would drive $z_k$ for example to the origin, would drive the state $x_k$ from $(1)$ to a value that is offset by $-\alpha$.

Comment: This answer addresses a more general affine problem. But if $b$ lies in the span of $B$ then the simpler solution would be to only offset the input $u_k$.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that minus alpha is the the fixed point of the uncontrolled system (i.e. the value x_k converges to when u_k = 0 for all k)? My motivation for introducing the state-independent constant (affine) term in the dynamics was actually to shift the fixed point of the system away from the origin while still having the controller drive the system to the origin. Can I learn such a controller in your setup, or is that not something an LQR-derived controller can do (does the fixed point and the desired setpoint have to be the same)?

Comment: @Jabby LQR stands for Linear Quadratic Regulator, where regulator means that the state is driven to the origin. For (3) the equilibrium is shifted to $(z_k,v_k)=(0,0)$ thus $(x_k,u_k)=(-\alpha,-\beta)$. This approach of translating the equilibrium can be sensitive to model inaccuracies. A more robust approach for this, that is still similar to LQR, would the [Linear Quadratic Integral (LQI)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ss.lqi.html).

Comment: If I understand correctly, LQR cannot be used to regulate (drive to zero) affine dynamical systems of the kind in (1)?

Comment: @Jabby Correct, the framework of LQR does not allow for static offsets, in either state or input. In order for infinite horizon LQR to have a solution it is required that the system $(A,B)$ is stabilizable, such that for the optimal solution both state and input asymptotically go to zero (and the associated cost function is finite). If there was any offset in either state and/or input, then the infinite horizon cost function would be unbounded.